# Open persistent connection

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c

I want to implement a system that will open a persistent connection between a server and a client (iPhone, in this case), and when it's needed send information using this connection.

How can I implement something like this?
Maybe somebody already wrote something that reach this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to use an [NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html). (The Cocoa libraries are incredibly rich, so there's nearly always a solution for common functionality like this.)

However, are you sure you really require a persistent connection? (Especially on a mobile device that may occasionally drop signal/switch from WiFi to 3G networks, etc.)

Comment: Does the NSStream can connect a server and a client, and when the server asks the client to do something, it will do it?

Comment: @Ron No - it's just a means of communicating between a client and a server, which is what you asked for. Have you actually read the class reference document that I linked to?